# Best way of extracting substring from a string by regex - javascript (string value below)

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

```
var stringname="function func() {alert('testing savecallback2');}"
```

This is the string value I was having hard time extracting.
I want to extract "func()" or any name that appends with "()".

Please help me up.

Comment: i don't understand what you want.you can provide a simple example

Comment: the substring which I need is the word that ends with "()". In this case, "func()" and store it in a new var.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want like this?

```js
var arr = "function func() {alert('testing savecallback2');}".match(/\s([A-Za-z0-9]+\(\))\s/);
console.log(arr[1])
```

Comment: hey thanx a bunch!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
var stringname="function func() {alert('testing savecallback2');}";
var start = stringname.search(/[a-zA-Z0-9]()/); 

//then use find string length
var string_length = start.length;

//then use substr()
var reuired_string = substr(start, string_length);
```

Comment: not working in my case!! what's the equivalent library function for substr() in jQuery standard?? srry I'm working in jquery stuff.

Comment: sorry, there is no equivalent for substr() in jquery as jquery itself is javascript

Answer (score 0):

With regex to find all that appends ()

```
var stringname="function func() { alert('testing savecallback2');}"
var regex = /[a-z_A-Z]+\([^\)]*\)(\.[^\)]*\))?/g;
var match;

while ((match = regex.exec(stringname) ) != null ) {
    console.log(match[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Without regex**

```
var stringname="function func() {alert('testing savecallback2');}"
var endIndex = stringname.indexOf("()");
var startIndex;
for(var i=13;i>=0;i--){
    if(stringname.charAt(i)==" "){
        startIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}
var result = stringname.substring(startIndex, endIndex+1);
```